# Allow android chrome to load unsafe scripts

Tags: security, chrome-for-android, javascript

When any site has mixed content (HTTPS + HTTP), and when you try to open HTTP content, on Desktop chrome, it shows a "shield" icon like screen below,

[image]

This allow user to load unsafe script.

However, the above option is not coming or not available when i open the same page in Android phone's chrome browser. My chrome app version is 71.0.3578.99

Any idea how to get above pop-up in android chrome to allow user to load unsafe scripts?

Comment: Can you provide a URL as an example?

Comment: the 1 i had an issue with i cannot share as i am not the owner of it. But basically this is easy to reproduce on any site whose page-1 is served over https and then page-2 is http. I will see if i can share such an example...

Comment: Starting with Chrome v79 the desktop version of Chrome will no longer load mixed content: https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html

Answer (score 1):

I just now encountered this problem. On my PC there was a warning "sheild" at the right side of the address bar, and I was able to click it and choose the option of load unsafe scripts.  On my Android tablet no such shield was present.  Just trying things, I clicked the address line, and it showed the URL along with a short menu of three choices, among them a pencil icon for editing. I chose that, then removed the "s" from the "https" in the URL, and that worked.

Comment: So, essentially, modify the address to http:// to eliminate the certification checks and the safe route? Spent alot of words there to say that without explaining the danger.

Comment: thanks, it works for me. I know there are security issues but i am only working on testing.